# SQL Query To Linq or Lambda Expression

Tags: .net, sql, linq, lambda

I just wonder to create the equivalent linq or lambda expression for the following sql query statement :

```
select(sum(a.credit) - sum(a.debit)) as total 
from table_A a inner join table_B b on 
a.accountid = b.id 
where a.[date] >= '2013-01-01' 
and a.[date] < '2013-03-27' 
and b.Name = 'MKBank'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i tried var p = db.Account_Transaction.join(db.Accounts,o=>o.AccountId,p=>p.ID,(o,p)=>new{o,p}).where(o=>o.o.Date >= '2013-01-01' && o.o.Date < '2013-03-31').GroupBy(grp=>new{grp.o.debit,grp.o.credit}).select(result=>new {result.sum(o=>o.o.credit-o=>o.o.debit)}); but i got an error like invalid anonymous declarator etc.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
            var qr = from a in lA
                 join b in lB on a.Id equals b.Id
                 where a.Date >= new DateTime(2013, 1, 1) &&
                 a.Date < new DateTime(2013, 3, 7) &&
                 b.Name == "MKBank"
                 select new
                 {
                     cr = a.credit,
                     db = a.debit
                 };

        var res = qr.Sum((x) => x.cr - x.db);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i tried and it seems it is not giving me any result at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is because of how you're declaring your anonymous type in the final select. You will need to specify the a member name if you want to specify anything other than a property name to select from. Read [Anonymous Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) for more details.

You also have a few other issues with your query. You also cannot compare `DateTime` and `string` values so you should construct your date parameters before passing them to your query. You shouldn't need to do any `.GroupBy` or a `.Select` either if you just want the total for one account. Finally `o => o.o.credit - o => o.o.debit` will not compile. I think what you want is `o => o.o.credit - o.o.debit`.

Try this instead:

```
DateTime beginDate = ...
DateTime endDate = ...
p = db.Account_Transaction.Join(
        db.Accounts,
        o => o.AccountId, 
        p => p.ID,
        (o, p) => new { o, p })
    .‌Where(o => o.o.Date >= beginDate && o.o.Date < endDate && o.p.Name == "MKBank")
    .Sum(o => o.o.credit - o.o.debit);
```